# Features supported in Syncfusion Grid control (Essential JS 2 for Angular)

Tags: syncfusion

I am trying to explore Syncfusion Grid control (Essential JS 2 for Angular).
Following is the link for documentation -
http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/
I have been trying to find whether the following facilities/support is available in the above mentioned grid -

1. Edit/Add/Delete row - Come to know that these features are not
   available for Essential JS 2 pure JavaScript controls. But what
   about the grid control(Essential JS 2 for Angular)
2. Search functionality  - I can see there are attributes like
   [allowSorting],[allowFiltering],[allowGrouping] to achieve
   sorting,filtering, grouping etc. Is there any similar property to
   perform Free text search on the grid? Or the only way is to take a
   reference of the grid 
   in the parent component (.ts file) and call search method
   that is present in GridComponent class?
3. Hierarchy Grid
4. Stacked Header
5. Is there any way to apply average/max/min/Sum etc operators on a numeric field during group by and displaying the result in the grid itself ? I mean if there are 3 columns (A-string, B-string, C- numeric) is there any way perform
   Sum on column C when user performs group by on Column A or Column B

   6. Reorder Column,
   7. Add/Remove Column

Answer (score 0):

1. Currently Editing support for Grid is not available in our Essential JS2 Angular. It will be available on our upcoming releases.
2. In Essential JS 2 Grid, searching behavior is always enabled, so that we are not provided `allowSearching` property in Grid component. You can search the grid records using the “search” method in GridComponent and we have created a simple sample in pluker.  Please refer the below link.
   Sample link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9TMJiGe0oh41eMixSo1?p=preview
3. Currently Hierarchy Grid feature is not available in our Essential JS2 Angular. It will be available in our next release.
4. This feature is available on our Grid component. 
   Sample link: http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/grid/column/stackedheader
5. Currently, Aggregate feature for Grid is not available in our Essential JS2 Angular. It will be available in our next release.
6. Reorder column feature is available in Grid component. 
   Please find the sample link: http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/grid/column/reorder
7. Visible/hidden Grid columns feature is available in Grid component.
   Sample link: http://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/grid/column/showhide